# Can I preload a full javascript library in electron.js and use it on the client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm creating an Electron.js project. I've added some npm packages for my project. Most of these are for the index.html. E.g. I've intalled vis-network (graphics js lib) for showing graphs. How can I preload these propely and use the libraries on the browser side? Or is there any other useful method to use npm packages on the browser side in Electron?

**preload.js**

```
const { contextBridge } = require("electron")
const { vis } = require("vis-network")

const attachedLibraries = {
    libVis : vis
}

contextBridge.exposeInIsolatedWorld("attachedLibraries", attachedLibraries)
```

**main.js**

```
const createWindow = () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload : 'preload.js'
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('view/index.html')
}
```

**npm package in node_modules**

[image: npm package hierarchy in node_modules]

Comment: Use `vite`, `webpack` or any other bundler that will do it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the package [electron-vite](https://evite.netlify.app) to do this! There are other options (like webpack as well), but this one is pretty well documented, particularly how they structure [preload scripts](https://evite.netlify.app/guide/dev.html#using-preload-scripts).